# Synchronize QGIS layout map scale with canvas scale

Tags: qgis, layouts, scale, dynamic

Is there any option to make the map scale match the canvas scale automatically? That is without having to use the "Set map scale to match main canvas scale" button.

Actually I expected it to be automatic by default and maybe have some button to stop this behavior and set the map scale to a fixed value. As this isn't how it works I guess there must be some other easy way of getting the automatic behavior but I haven't found it so far (no option, no switch button, no variable...). Is there anything I missed?

By the way I know python expressions could help but I'm looking for a built-in functionality.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton Don't know how to be moreprecise about what I have tried. I already said I found no option, switch or variable to do what I want. So that's what I've looked for both in the layout composer and the documentation during a whole morning of work and there's where I'm stuck. I posted this here as my last resource before accepting there's no such functionality, with the hope that someone would tell me "yeah, there's that 'sort of hidden' option (or whatever) that does just that".

Comment: when were you expecting it to happen? what is wrong with pressing the set scale button when needed?

Comment: I expected that after changing the canvas scale the layout map scale would change accordingly too, just by refreshing the layout view (zooming in/out for example). But there's no option in the Map properties or a variable storing the canvas scale to use it in the Scale option.

Comment: but that would break my (your) map layout probably by acident

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there's no option to automatically change the map scale in a layout when the canvas scale changes.

@IanTurton I don't see why this option would break the map layout. You would activate it on purpose.
There's many other features that would break it too then if you are unaware of what you are doing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).